# How to replace a string between double brackets while typing?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a form that contains a filed. Value of field will replace a string between double bracket in the template. here example :

1. first, I type value in field with id "username".
2. second, the string between `<textarea></textarea>` with double bracket `{{username}}` (which is It has been around since it was loaded) will replace by value that I type in first form.

I try the same thing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nmx04h1o/3/) but it's not work with my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way how you could do it:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[id]')];

const template = textarea.value;

function update() {
  textarea.value = inputs.reduce((acc, i) => acc.replace(new RegExp(`\\{\\{\\s*${i.id}\\s*\\}\\}`, 'g'), i.value), template);
}

inputs.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('input', update));
update();
```

```html
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input id="username" />
<br />
<label for="age">Age:</label>
<input id="age" />
<br /><br />
<textarea readonly="readonly">user: {{username}} age: {{age}}</textarea>
```

Comment: almost correct, but when i say template I mean there some string between double bracket in `textarea` from the beginning. such as like this : <textarea>name : {{username}}</textarea> when I input some value in filed text with id username it will replace the {{username}} in textarea. I change your code with replace addEventListener listen into username field, but it just read first character.

Comment: @DanielAlfianto But that's exactly what this code does. If you input `name: {{username}}` in the textarea, the text will be replaced to `name: xxx` and the `xxx` will be the value in `#username`

Comment: I mean user can't input anything in textarea. user only input in field text that will replace string between double bracket in textarea which is been there since first load.

Comment: @DanielAlfianto I know what you mean by now, check the updated answer

Comment: yeah thank you very much. but I will add a little bit code in your code combine with Lawrence Cherone code. Thank you very much guys?

Comment: @DanielAlfianto If you want it to be dynamic, it doesn't have to be that complicated. Please check the updated answer again, you can add as many inputs as you want. just to make sure the `id`s of the inputs match whatever in `{{}}`

Comment: very nice. thanks you so much. this is what i need. the ids will match whatever in double bracket. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

Split template from the result, this way you can define the template and update the username or any other fields without needing to go through it and fix after you entered first char which is what will happen if the template is ever predefined.

```js
// define fields
let fields = {
  'username': document.querySelector('input[name="username"]'),
  'when': document.querySelector('input[name="when"]')
}

// working textareas
const template = document.querySelector('textarea[name="template"]');
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea[name="template-rendered"]');

// get fields values and render into textarea value
function renderTemplate() {
  let vars = {}

  for (let field in fields)
    if (fields[field].value) vars[field] = fields[field].value

  textarea.value = template.value.replace(/\{{[ ]{0,}([\w\_-]{1,})[ ]{0,}}}/gi, function(...match) {
    return typeof vars[match[1]] !== 'undefined' ? vars[match[1]] : `{{ ${match[1]} }}`
  })
}

// template update event
template.addEventListener('input', renderTemplate);

// attach input events
for (let field in fields)
  fields[field].addEventListener('input', renderTemplate);
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input name="username" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="when">When:</label>
  <input id="when" name="when" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="username">Template:</label>
  <textarea id="template" name="template">Hello {{ username }}, how are you {{ when }}?</textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="result">Result:</label>
  <textarea id="result" name="template-rendered"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much it help me so much. Do you think I can loop the variable using php so i'ts not jus username and when.. because the form I made is dynamic. or do you have any suggest?

Comment: sure, you could define an array of fields and loop over them to generate the js maintaining the same convention as *username* and *when*, though if you want different input types like dates or selects etc then it would get a little more complicated. If you want to parse the template in php and just send up the fields the same regex can be used https://gist.github.com/lcherone/f7ef70406c7c84aeb7d64566afb63bb8

Answer (score 0):

after a few tries finally.

```js
function myFunction(value) {


  String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index,index2, replacement,awal) {
    return this.substr(awal.length-index, index+2) + replacement + this.substr(index2);
  }
  
  var p=document.getElementById("p");

  var str = p.value;
  var index1 = str.indexOf("{{");
  var index2 = str.indexOf("}}");
  
  var awalan=str.split('{{')[0];
  
 
    p.value=(str.replaceAt(index1,index2, value,awalan));
 
  
}
```

```html
<input onInput="myFunction(this.value)"/>
<br>
<br>
<Textarea id="p">my name is {{username}} im living on earth.</textarea>
```